# Tomcat jdbc pool doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, pooling

I am having a slight problem with using JDBC tomcat pool. I have properly defined the resource in context.xml, as well as referring to it in web.xml. Now in my Database access method, I would like to somehow get a data source for when a user get something from the database. However, when I type this in:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/testDB");
```

I get the error message "InitialContext cannot be resolved to a type". What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you import `InitialContext`?

Comment: Awesome! I added my comment as an answer, since it worked would you please accept it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to import `InitialContext`, it sounds like it is missing to the compiler.